# AS3 Sort XML File by Attribute (Numerically)

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm trying to sort an XML document in AS3 by attribute. I have a function for this written:

```
        public static function sortXMLByAttribute($xml:XML,$attribute:String,$options:Object=null,$copy:Boolean = false):XML
    {
        var xmlArray:Array  = new Array();

        var item:XML;

        for each(item in $xml.children())
        {
            var object:Object = {data:item, order:item.attribute($attribute)};
            xmlArray.push(object);
        }

        //sort using the power of Array.sortOn()
        xmlArray.sortOn('order',$options);

        //create a new XMLList with sorted XML
        var sortedXmlList:XMLList = new XMLList();
        var xmlObject:Object;
        for each(xmlObject in xmlArray )
        {
            sortedXmlList += xmlObject.data;
        }

        if($copy)
        {
            //don't modify original
            return  $xml.copy().setChildren(sortedXmlList);
        }
        else
        {
            //original modified
            return $xml.setChildren(sortedXmlList);
        }
    }
```

For some reason this is not correctly changing the order of the objects by the attribute I'm using.

Here is where it's being called:

```
            trace(this.pActiveItemXML);
            trace(sortXMLByAttribute(this.pActiveItemXML, 'quantity', Array.DESCENDING | Array.NUMERIC, true));
```

And here's the trace statement of the first and the second trace. You can see it's changing their order, but not in numeric order of 'quantity':

TRACE 1:

```
 <name>My Room</name>
  <object>
    <type>Table</type>
    <id>mc_table001</id>
    <library>mc_table001</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>4</quantity>
  </object>
  <object>
    <type>Pillow</type>
    <id>cushion001</id>
    <library>cushion_group01</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>4</quantity>
  </object>
  <object>
    <type>Pillow</type>
    <id>cushion002</id>
    <library>cushion_group01</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>3</quantity>
  </object>
  <object>
    <type>Lamp</type>
    <id>lamp001</id>
    <library>lamp_group01</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>3</quantity>
  </object>
  <object>
    <type>Lamp</type>
    <id>lamp002</id>
    <library>lamp_group01</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
  </object>
  <object>
    <type>Lamp</type>
    <id>lamp003</id>
    <library>lamp_group01</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>4</quantity>
  </object>
</wardrobe>
```

TRACE 2:

```
<object>
    <type>Pillow</type>
    <id>cushion002</id>
    <library>cushion_group01</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>3</quantity>
  </object>
  <object>
    <type>Table</type>
    <id>mc_table001</id>
    <library>mc_table001</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>4</quantity>
  </object>
  <object>
    <type>Pillow</type>
    <id>cushion001</id>
    <library>cushion_group01</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>4</quantity>
  </object>
  <name>My Room</name>
  <object>
    <type>Lamp</type>
    <id>lamp001</id>
    <library>lamp_group01</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>3</quantity>
  </object>
  <object>
    <type>Lamp</type>
    <id>lamp002</id>
    <library>lamp_group01</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
  </object>
  <object>
    <type>Lamp</type>
    <id>lamp003</id>
    <library>lamp_group01</library>
    <ondisplay>1</ondisplay>
    <quantity>4</quantity>
  </object>
</wardrobe>
```

If anyone could shed some light on where I'm going wrong that would be massively appreciated.

Comment: You want to sort by quantity? Isn't quantity always 5 in your example?

Comment: My mistake, wrong part...I've edited now.